# Mysql - remove first dot ocurrence

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to remove a first ocurrence of a point in a string, but replace change all occurrence...

```
-123.456.00 -> 123456.00
123.456.00 -> 123456.00
1.234.00 -> 1234.00
```

Comment: Show how you are trying to do it.

Comment: You should actually store numbers in an according data type and not as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT round(replace("123.456.00", ".", "")/100, 2)
```

This will give you 123456.00 or 123456,00 depends on your region.

Comment: Thanks Advice, this was enouth